# Variables not splitting as expected in VB.Net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, for-loop, split

I'm trying to read each line from a text file, and then assign the 4 numbers there each to a variable. However, when I run the code, the last of the 4 variabls seems to be holding everything after (and including) the last number on that line.

What I'm reading (a snippet):

```
490 450 490 450
490 450 490 450
490 451 488 451
485 453 482 455
478 456 474 458
469 459 469 459
464 461 460 462
456 463 451 465
```

The code I'm using:

```
For Each Line As String In File.ReadLines("\\path\to\my\file")
    Dim Coords() As String = Split(fileReader, " ", 4)
    Dim Coord0 As Int16 = Coords(0)
    Dim Coord1 As Int16 = Coords(1)
    Dim Coord2 As Int16 = Coords(2)
    Dim Coord3 As Int16 = Coords(3)
    ' more code here to use those variables
Next
```

I've used Trim() on each line, so there are no spaces before or after the 4 sets of numbers in each line.
I'm trying to convert each of the numbers (which is recorded as a string into an integer).

I run the code, and it results in an exception, When I analyze the values of the variables, I get:

```
Coord0 = 490
Coord1 = 450
Coord2 = 490
Coord3 = 0
Coords(0) = "490"
Coords(1) = "450"
Coords(2) = "490"
Coords(3) = "450" & vbCrLf & "490 450 490 450" & vbCrLf & "490 451 488 451" & vbCrLf & "485 453 482 455" & vbCrLf & "478 456 474 458"
```

And keeps going all the way to the end of the file.

So the way that I see it is that it has converted the 1st 3 variables in the array to integers (awesome), but then on the last integer on the first line, is seems to just give up and think that the entire rest of the file is all a part of that string, and there's no way in hell that it can turn that into a number, so It give's up and thows an exception.

I've done a bit of a dirty hack to "skip" reading the last variable by editing the creation script to save an extra space and character at the end of each line. Then using `Dim Coords() As String = Split(fileReader, " ", 5)` (with a 5 instead of a 4).

I then simply never referrence the `Coords(5)`; which feels like I'm cheating.

What would be the best way to go about fixing this properly?

Extra info:
I learned VB5 and VB6 back when they were new. I've moved over to using GNU/Linux since then and have been there for the last long time. I now however need to write something for windows and got a hold of Visual Studio and trying to code it up in VB.Net.

Comment: `Dim Coords = Line.Split() Dim Coord0 = CInt(Coords(0))` or `Dim Coord0 = Convert.ToInt16(Coords(0))` or `Dim Coord0 = CShort(Coords(0))`, if you actually want a Short (Int16). -- As noted in the answer, that `fileReader` is undeclared (its origin is unknown) and clearly counter-productive here. The `Line` string contains your values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is that `fileReader` you are passing to `Split()`? Shouldn't that be

```
Dim Coords() As String = Split(Line, " ", 4)
```

It seems like the `fileReader` you have there is also reading the file, and with `Split()` you read at most 4 tokens from it. So you are reading the first 3 tokens separated by a space, and the entire rest of the file is put into the 4th token.

Comment: The line is from before the for loop - sorry. it's the variable holding the data from the file `Dim fileReader As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("\\path\to\my\file")` And you're right - I do seem to be grabbing that file twice. Seems like more bug hunting is in order.